# libgdx 0.9.8, can't run Particle Editor

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

I have downloaded libgdx 0.9.8 and trying to run particle editor from the gdx-tools JAR(https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ParticleEditor):

```
java -cp gdx.jar;gdx-natives.jar;gdx-backend-lwjgl.jar;gdx-backend-lwjgl-natives.jar;extensions\gdx-tools\gdx-tools.jar com.badlogic.gdx.tools.particleeditor.ParticleEditor
```

but I continuously getting following error:

```
java -cp gdx.jar;gdx-natives.jar;gdx-backend-lwjgl.jar;gdx-backend
-lwjgl-natives.jar;extensions\gdx-tools\gdx-tools.jar com.badlogic.gdx.tools.par
ticleeditor.ParticleEditor
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: default.fnt (Interna
l)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:127)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont$BitmapFontData.<init>(Bitmap
Font.java:711)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont.<init>(BitmapFont.java:114)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont.<init>(BitmapFont.java:106)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.tools.particleeditor.ParticleEditor$Renderer.create(
ParticleEditor.java:326)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglCanvas.create(LwjglCanvas.java:1
86)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglCanvas$1.addNotify(LwjglCanvas.j
ava:90)
        at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2576)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4693)
        at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2576)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4693)
        at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2576)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4693)
        at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2576)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4693)
        at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2576)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4693)
        at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2576)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4693)
        at javax.swing.JRootPane.addNotify(JRootPane.java:738)
        at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2576)
        at java.awt.Window.addNotify(Window.java:664)
        at java.awt.Frame.addNotify(Frame.java:470)
        at java.awt.Window.show(Window.java:860)
        at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1591)
        at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1543)
        at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:843)
```

Where is my mistake and how it could be solved ?

Comment: I would suggest downloading latest from here: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/ and running that command from the extracted folder (libgdx-nightly-latest)

Comment: just tested the last nightlie works

Comment: Thanks ! Please add it as an answer and I'll mark it as a correct answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the jar file is missing the assets content from:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/extensions/gdx-tools/assets

The issue seems to be fixed in nightly build. Just in case you still need 0.9.8, you may unjar the gdx-tools.jar, download and copy all the files to right under the root folder of the jar file and re-jar it.